# passing appointment.id to booking.appointment_id rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameter-passing

I have a an Appointments object and a Bookings object. Bookings belongs to Appointments and Appointments has_many bookings.

I want to pass the appointment ID to bookings.appointment_id on create. How can I do this?

*I have edited my code in response to jordanandree suggestions. Now I am getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in BookingsController#new
undefined method `bookings' for nil:NilClass
```

In my home page view I have:

```
<% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
    <%= link_to "new Booking", new_appointment_booking_path(appointment)%>
<%end%>
```

Bookings Controller:

```
def new
    @booking = @appointment.bookings.new 
    ...

 def create
     @booking = @appointment.bookings.new(params[:booking])
    ...
```

routes

```
resources :appointments do
    resources :bookings
 end
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Rake Routes:

```
   POST   /appointments/:appointment_id/bookings(.:format)  bookings#create 
   GET    /appointments/:appointment_id/bookings/new(.:format)  bookings#new
   GET    /appointments/:appointment_id/bookings/:id/edit(.:format) bookings#edit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails associations allows for you to create a record based on an existing record. What you have currently is a bit overkill with the parameters you have passing from the form to controller.

For example, you can change your `create` method to follow the same association pattern you've declared for your Booking and Appointment models:

```
@booking = @appointment.bookings.new(params[:booking])
```

This will take the id of the already-present `@appointment` record and set it on the new `@booking` instance variable.

Also, I would take a look at [nested resource routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). Not sure what your routes currently look like for the two models, but it could look something like this:

```
resources :appointments do
  resources :bookings
end
```

This will provide a cleaner approach to your forms where you have `new_booking_path`. It would change to `new_appointment_booking_path(@appointment)`. This would pass the ID of appointment to your booking controller where you can than create associated records for the appointment.

Comment: thanks Jordan, I updated the code. Now the program is passing in the right appointment_id parameter but I am receiving a no method error. How do I remedy this?

Comment: Are you sure you have the @appointment instance variable set in your `create` controller method _before_ you have `@booking = @appointment.bookings.new(params[:booking])`?

Comment: what would that look like? I put @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:appointment_id]) before and I got the following error: Couldn't find Appointment without an ID

Comment: did you follow the nested resource routing suggestion I made above? that would provide you with the appointment_id in the URL params. The no method error and appointment error are a result of the appointment_id not being passed to your `create` method.

Comment: I had that in there. I also had an extra (resources :bookings) outside of the nested one. Removing that gives me the following error: No route matches [POST] "/bookings".

Comment: you can have both resources routes. The nested resources routes for appointments > bookings is useful to match the association of your models. Have you updated your `link_to` to pass the new route `new_appointment_booking_path(@appointment)`?

Comment: Ya I have the link_to as you provided. Regarding routes: When I have both resource routes I get this error: Couldn't find Appointment without an ID, when I only have the nested one I get No route matches [POST] "/bookings"

Comment: regarding the `@appointment` instance var not being set, check to make sure you are correctly passing the id for the Appointment. its either `params[:id]` or `params[:appointment_id]`. For routes, run `rake routes` in command line to see where your `create` route is for a new booking.